# Why do Pentecostalists often use the word "fire" during exorcisms?

Tags: pentecostalism, exorcism

In the Pentecostal Church you often see people use the word "fire" during exorcisms. Why? To burn the demon out?

I would like to see some scripture that can back up the doctrine or culture.

Comment: It would help the question a little if you could give quotes (or share a video or something) showing how these pentecostals talk about exorcisms and fire.

Comment: @curiousdannii  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXAWtnXkt6Q

Comment: @curiousdannii John Zavlaris Ministries .Not sure if they are pentecostal

Comment: Please [edit] the question and put in some quotes for those who aren't able to watch a video.

Comment: Who has the time to watch a 10 hour video! Could you please edit in some quotes or at least some time  footage notes as to where to look for your points of interest?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two basic analogies for fire in the NT: first is the *everlasting
fire* the condemned souls are cast into; the second one is the *purifying
fire* associated with the Holy Spirit. Mt 25:41 is an example of the former:

> Then shall he say also unto them on the left hand, Depart from me,
>   ye cursed, into everlasting fire, prepared for the devil and his angels:

Also Luke 9:54:

> And when his disciples James and John saw this, they said, Lord, wilt thou
>   that we command fire to come down from heaven, and consume them, even as
>   Elias did?

Of the second, there's Mt 3:11:

> I indeed baptize you with water unto repentance. but he that cometh
>   after me is mightier than I, whose shoes I am not worthy to bear:
>   he shall baptize you with the Holy Ghost, and with fire:

And obviously, the famous Pentecost narrative from Acts 2:

> 1 When the day of Pentecost came, they were all together in one place.
>   2 Suddenly a sound like the blowing of a violent wind came from heaven
>   and filled the whole house where they were sitting.
>   3 They saw what seemed to be *tongues of fire* that separated and came
>   to rest on each of them.

Now, the thing about Pentecostalism is that there isn't a *Catechism* or
some sort of definitive compendium of doctrine, but in general, a pastor
will invoke fire as a combination of the two metaphors: the fire that
purifies the possessed person from the unclean spirit, and the fire that
punishes the same unclean spirit in the “place prepared for the devil and
his angels.”